# UITableViewCell bad view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When you compile your app with Archive and upload to a website for download from iphone. UITableView views are dislocated. However compiling directly from xcode, view displays correctly ... is very strange, without touching anything, upload it unsettles everything, and build from xcode not ... Why?

Archive compiled, uploaded to the server and installed on iphone.-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYYGD.png

Compiling directly from xcode in iphone.-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoKU7.png

Thanks

Comment: Archive and debug builds use different schemes in Xcode. Do you have any preprocessor definitions or conditional includes in place?

Comment: Perfect, I've put in Archive debug and now display properly. It will review all parameters of Release.

Thank you!